# Аппаратный генератор случайных чисел

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Нашел в интернете код, где используется аппаратный генератор случайных чисел. [Хабр](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/72844/)

Отрывок из кода:

```
// Генерируем случайную последовательность при помощи аппаратного генератора
HardkeyRandomGenerator random_generator;
RawData random_data = random_generator.GenerateRandom(total_games * 3);
```

Как это можно заменить?

Comment: Нарандомить просто числа в диапазоне ?

Comment: Ну и статья. Модная архитектура с классами, якобы аппаратный ГСЧ... А потом автор по ошибке печатает вероятность победы для двух разных стратегий из одной из тоже же переменной; и его не смущает, что вероятность не сходится с написанным рядом количеством побед...

Comment: Например [вот так](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25)

Comment: вопрос зачем он если есть rand ??

Comment: `/dev/urandom` ?